# Centre two divs, one with a logo and one with text, side by side on top of a html5 video and still be responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I am currently trying to build a website for my university project to promote my gaming YouTube channel. On the main page i have set up a short, looping html5 video to have as a background. Then I wish to put a logo and a heading and some text on top of it. I also then have splitter images to separate the sections of the page.

I have got the layering right for the z-index and I have got a piece of jQuery code which resizes the video working fine. My problem is that I just cant for the life of me work out how to centre the image and text on the screen in the middle of the video and have it stay like that and resize with the window size. I would like this website to work on mobile as well hence the responsive stuff. I also want to have the splitter image at the bottom of the video at all times.

I think I am mostly there with what I'm trying to accomplish but I just cant get it quite right.

Here is the link to the website: http://www.willcaddy.com/

Here is a link to the pastebin code if that's easier: http://pastebin.com/vnH7LRNm

If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just playing around with the inspect element in chrome and by doing this I was able to get your image and text all centered over the video

```
.videoContainer {
 /* display: inline-block; */
    height: 54vw;
    width: /*whatever you want*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

Remove the inline block and then use whatever value you want for the width, i tried it with 400px and for me it was nicely centered. You may need to use a media query or two to handle the placement on smaller screen sizes

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get what you mean and I have got it working mostly how I want. Just wondering if there is an easy way to get the text to centre  half way up the logo like in this screen shot:

http://postimg.org/image/83q1d2297/

And still be responsive?

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I have got it working how I want in somewhat of a hacky fashion lol but I have a weird issue with foundation. The html5 video background is clipping through the navbar when it is in mobile size and makes it go red. I cant find out what's causing it :-( Any ideas? 

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using `float: left;` for the container inhibiting the picture and text. You might want to change that if you want it centered. If you use `margin: auto;` for the div inside "willCaddyTextAll", that should solve the problem.

When it comes to centering the content inside that Div, you can use `text-align: center;` for text, and center the image to your liking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It did help :-) Just got one more issue to solve which I have commented on hispowerlevelisover9000's post. Any ideas? 

Much appreciated :-) Thanks :-)

Comment: Glad i could help :-) Regarding your last problem, i think setting `max-height: 100%;` would help!